# Is there a left-orderable profinite group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, ordered-groups

Is there a nontrivial profinite group $G$ with a binary transitive relation $<$ such that

1. $x<y$ implies $x\neq y$, and for any different $x,y \in G$ either $x < y$ or $y < x$ and such that for any $x,y,z \in G$ we have that $x < y$ implies that $zx < zy$ (i.e., $<$ defines a left-invariant strict total order)
2. $\{(x,y):x<y\}$ is open?

Comment: My guess would be that only $G = \{1\}$ works (finite groups are profinite). I don't have any proofs though.

Comment: @jmc maybe continuous orders should be considered since by a result of Levi every abelian group with no torsion is orderable and this works for the additive profinite p-adic groups.

Comment: Ok, yes, a relation with the topology is very reasonable. (I kind of assumed it, but indeed, you did not state it.)

Comment: If the order is closed in the topology on the direct product the answer is no by reduction to the finite case I believe.

Comment: Benjamin, I do not understand your comment. The profinite group is not necessarily a product of finite groups.

Comment: The partial order is a set of ordered pairs. If this is set is closed in the product topology the ordering will be trivial.

Comment: I added the condition that the graph of $<$ is open, since the question is not very interesting without it (cf the remark on torsion-free abelian groups) and because it's the assumption made in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such ordering, which is compatible with the profinite topology in the following way: If $x<y$, then there are small neighbourhoods $U, V$ of $x, y$, such that $u<v$ for all $u\in U, v\in V$.

To see this note that If $x>1$, then $x^n>1$ for all $n>0$ and $x^n<1$ for all $n<0$. But in the pro-finite topology, the sequence $x^{n!-1}$ converges to $x^{-1}$, so the set $\{x:x\geq 1\}$ is not closed. But this contradicts our assumption that the ordering is compatible with the topology.